# variadic / arbitrary number of *args or ** kwargs in str.format() in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting, args, keyword-argument

I'm making a socket client and need to define a function which sends the following kind of message to server: `sometext,[name_1],[name_2],...,[name_n]`. Actually the message is more complex, but for the sake of an example I simplified it.

Where:

- `...` - represents the rest of the names (comma delimited) between name_2 and the last name_n
- there could be arbitrary number of names each time

I know there are `*args` and `**kwargs`, but how to correctly use them in this case with `str.format()`? I need something like this:

```
def send_names(*args):
    print('sometext,{*args},'.format(*args)) # as an example we just print
```

I know this code doesn't work because `{*args}` is illegal here.
The code works when I know the number of `*args` beforehand, like in here:

```
def send_names(*args):
    print('sometext,{0},{1},{2}'.format(*args)) # as an example we just print
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can join the `*args` to accomplish what you want:

```
def send_names(*args):
    print('sometext, {0}'.format(', '.join(args)))

send_names('message1', 'message2', 'message3')
```

result:

```
sometext, message1, message2, message3
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `*args` or `**kwargs` to apply to a variable number of slots, no. You'd have to create the slots yourself based on the length:

```
','.join(['{}'] * len(args)).format(*args)
```

You can then interpolate the result of that into another template as needed. The above works with any type of argument normally accepted by a formatting slot.

Demo:

```
>>> args = ('foo', 'bar')
>>> ','.join(['{}'] * len(args)).format(*args)
'foo,bar'
>>> args = ('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
>>> ','.join(['{}'] * len(args)).format(*args)
'foo,bar,baz'
>>> args = (1, 2, 3)
>>> ','.join(['{}'] * len(args)).format(*args)
'1,2,3'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should avoid using `.format` and just `', '.join` the args as needed. You didn't mention any specific reason why you need to `.format` the strings in the question. Just like the solution by @Selcuk

Comment: To be able to add 'sometext'?

Comment: In fact yes, there is no reason for me to confine myself to `.format`, I'm just trying to understand the syntax. And, of course, I will accept and use other valid solutions if they are simpler. When I asked the question, I just didn't know other possibilities.

Comment: @Selcuk To clarify i meant like the solution by you, not by Martijn, which seems redundant